# Commiting outer transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table  dbo.Test (id INT)

create PROCEDURE TestProcedure1
as
begin
    exec TestProcedure2
    insert into Test values (2)
end


create PROCEDURE TestProcedure2
as
begin

begin transaction
    insert into Test values (2)
end
```

Now run this:

```
exec TestProcedure1 commit
```

the error output is below:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure TestProcedure2, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure TestProcedure1, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
```

I understand the reason for the error i.e. there is no end transaction in TestProcedure2.  What are the implications of this? After I saw the error I ran the SQL statement below:

```
select * from dbo.Test
```

This returned two rows i.e. the outer transaction committed the inner transaction.  I have two questions:

```
1) Does the outer transaction always commit the inner transaction.
2) After executing the select statement I executed the following commands:

commit
commit

What affect does running two commit statements have in this scenario?
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, if outer committed, inner also committed. If outer rolled back, all inner rolled back
2. You must use `commit` operator for all `begin tran` operators

Better read this to understand nested transactions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx